# How to retrieve only visible node text with lxml

Tags: python, lxml

How do you use the Python package [lxml](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-element-methods) to retrieve visible text in a node, excluding any child nodes or hidden elements?

All I can find in the docs is `node.text_content()`, but all that does is strip out html tags, returning all text at all depths regardless of visibility. I also tried `node.text`, but that seems to just return None for all nodes.

Comment: What do you mean by "visibility"? CSS? That's not `lxml`'s domain, `lxml` is just an XML / (X)HTML parser.

Comment: Friend already asked on stackower

Comment: @LukasGraf, Sure it is. It includes cssselect and xpath support. CSS isn't magic. It's just text. I should be able to search for text at all depths and under different types of classes and styles...but their docs only show you how to find all or nothing. But I'd be happy to find a way to find text at a particular node.

Comment: @Cerin No, it really is not. XPath has nothing to do with CSS. And cssselect is a tiny fraction of the CSS spec, just the selector - that's just a convenience module to translate CSS selectors to XPath. Having a full blown CSS *parser* would not even be enough to determine node visibility. You'd need an actual CSS layout engine that considers inheritance and selector specificity to determine the computed styles for a node.

Comment: As for the element text, the [docs](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-contain-text) are pretty clear: "*The two properties `.text` and `.tail` are enough to represent any text content in an XML document.*". So in order to extract the *flat* (non-recursively) text contents from a node, something like `u''.join([node.text] + [c.tail for c in node.iterchildren()])` should be enough.

Comment: @LukasGraf, You misunderstand. I don't need to parse complex CSS expressions or scan browser windows. I just need to check for the existence of "display:none" in the style attribute. That's well within lxml's abilities. In any case, I've figured it out.

Comment: how'd you do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath to extract text you need.
Since you need visible text only, put `/text()` in your xpath.

For example, if I need to extract your second paragraph:

```
import requests
from lxml import etree
r = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029681/how-to-retrieve-only-visible-node-text-with-lxml")
html = etree.HTML(r.text)
list_of_text = html.xpath('//*[@id="question"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/p//text()') #xpath copied from browser
''.join(list_of_text)
```

You will get:

```
'How do you use the Python package lxml to retrieve visible text in a node, excluding any child nodes or hidden elements?All I can find in the docs is node.text_content(), but all that does is strip out html tags, returning all text at all depths regardless of visibility. I also tried node.text, but that seems to just return None for all nodes.'
```

Note that `//text()` is slightly different from `/text()`, will choose whatever nodes in between the parent node to the last children node.